# Executing a cmd using "system()" doesn't look for path

Tags: c++, cmd, system

I'm trying to execute a graphviz/dot cmd from within my program,
but I'm still getting the error `sh: dot: command not found`.

So that's the line that matters:

```
system("dot -Tpng myfile.txt -o mypic.png");
```

Executing it on the terminal works pretty well, cause dot is set into my path variable.
Trying to execute the same programmatically ends up in the described error.

Is there any trick using the system cmd where I have to mention my path additionally?
(Btw: I already did include stdlib.h, dunno wether that's important...)

Thx a lot!

Comment: What do you mean 'dot is set into my path variable'?  If you mean '`PATH` contains the directory where `dot` lives', then your problem is not obvious. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: You might want to have a sytem that prints PATH and see if it is what you think it is

Comment: Does `sh -c 'dot -Tpng myfile.txt -o mypic.png'`, when executed exactly the same way you execute your application, work?

Comment: How an where do you add the directory where `dot` lives into `PATH`? And how do you execute your application? Because obviously you are setting it so the setting does not make it to the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("PATH=$PATH:<YOUR PATH TO **dot**>;<**dot** and the rest>");
}
```

as shocking as it seems, this works for me ...
(obviously replace between < > ... )

Comment: didn't work for me, I used the full path in the systemCmd instead. Otherwise this wasn't even necessary on linux, but on osx. Thanks anyway.